# hybris search and filters in product cockpit

Tags: e-commerce, customization, sap-commerce-cloud

In the product cockpit of the backoffice there is a search feature to which you can add some filters , I would like to add some of my own attributes to the filters.

In the my custom backoffice extension in the config.xml i added

```
<context type="MyProduct" component="pcmbackoffice-fulltext-search" module="pcmbackoffice">
    <ful:fulltext-search xmlns:ful="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/fulltextsearch" xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <ful:field-list>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.Name"/>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.Type"/>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.isActive"/>
        </ful:field-list>
        <ful:preferred-search-strategy>solr</ful:preferred-search-strategy>
        <ful:operator>OR</ful:operator>
    </ful:fulltext-search>
</context>
```

i then ran a clean all and an update from the hac , but the changes are not shown. in the console i see

```
[DefaultFieldQueryFieldRenderer] Unable to determine field configuration for 
field 'MyProduct.Name' in 'pcmbackoffice-collectionBrowser- 
fulltextsearch'
```

I have also tried the config below.

```
 <context type="MyProduct" component="pcmbackoffice-fulltext-search" module="pcmbackoffice">
    <ful:fulltext-search xmlns:ful="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/config/fulltextsearch" xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <ful:field-list>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.Name"/>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.Type"/>
            <ful:field name="MyProduct.isActive"/>
        </ful:field-list>
        <ful:preferred-search-strategy>solr</ful:preferred-search-strategy>
        <ful:operator>OR</ful:operator>
    </ful:fulltext-search>
</context>
```

which does not change the default settings (product).

any help on how to configure the search and filters in the product cockpit would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow step which is described in [document](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/bad6bfb882114bd090b46fc64de990aa.html).
You need to configure your variant for backoffice search solr indexing at System > Search and Navigation > Indexed Types.

Comment: Hi thanks , i looked at the like and was able to get the filters present. But I can't make this persistent if I initialize the configuration is gone.

Comment: Some impex may be remove existing before importing news one. You can search all impex files for that item type.